# Printing a number rounded off to a million with siunitx in tables

Tags: tables, siunitx

How do I use `table-omit-exponent` property (or something else) from `siunitx` to skip the exponent and print the unit as `M` for a million instead of getting the numbers printed in the format `4.32x10^6` in the following example? I understand that the unit `M` can be defined as a custom unit. I am struggling to remove the exponent part. Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \sisetup{round-mode=places, round-precision=2, table-format=1.3, 
    scientific-notation=fixed, fixed-exponent=6, table-omit-exponent}
    \begin{tabular}
    { p{50mm} S S}
    \toprule
    Field & {col1} & {col2} 
    \\ 
    \midrule
    Property1 & \num{4321673} & \num{74098261}
    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For starters, remove `\num` from the table entries...

Comment: and.. provide a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28557) which has `\documentclass` `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`

Comment: Oops. I am gonna use my "new contributor" card as an excuse for not adding an MWE. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for that suggestion. Removing `\num` did the trick apparently!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `\num` did the trick for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\DeclareSIUnit{\million}{M}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \sisetup{round-mode=places, round-precision=2, table-format=3.3, 
    scientific-notation=fixed, fixed-exponent=6, table-omit-exponent}
    \begin{tabular}
    { p{40mm} S S}
    \toprule
    Field & {col1} & {col2} 
    \\ 
    \midrule
    Property1 & 4321673 \si{\million} & 74098261 \si{\million}
    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Gives the table

```
_____________________________
Field      col1      col2
_____________________________
Property1  4.32  M   74.10  M
_____________________________
```

Still has an ugly spacing between the number and `M`. Since there are no other answers, I will keep it here.

Comment: Actually, it's more than that. You also added `\million`.